# OpenCV does not work with PyCharm after upgrading to Mac OS 11 (Big Sur)

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, pycharm, macos-big-sur

I had OpenCV working fine with PyCharm CE and Python 3.8.  Then I upgraded the Mac OS to Big Sur and it stopped working.  I reinstalled OpenCV as follows with no effect:

pip3 install opencv-python

pip3 install opencv-contrib-python

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that the solution was to downgrade the opencv version.  In Pycharm, the process is as follows:

1. In Preferences, go to Python interpreter. You will see the current versions of opencv-contrib-python and opencv-python which may be the same as the latest version.
   That is the problem.[image]
2. Double click on the current version of opencv-contrib-python to open this screen:

[image]

3. Check the specify version checkbox and find version 4.1.2.30. Then click Install Package and wait a few seconds to get a message that package was successfully installed. Press OK and you should see opencv-conbtrib-python downgraded to the appropriate version.
4. After step 3, opencv-python may have also downgraded to the appropriate version 4.2.0.34. If it hasn't, follow the same process to downgrade opencv-python to 4.2.0.34.  At the end, your python interpreter screen should look like this:

[image]

That should do it. Test it to make sure it works.